# How to install mySQL 5.6.23 using puppetlabs-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.6, puppetlabs-mysql

**Environment :**

- Vagrant (VirtualBox)
- Ubuntu 14
- Puppet

-Puppetlabs-mysql (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql)

**Problem**:

Using puppetlabs-mysql (Version 3.6.1) I am trying to install mySQL 5.6.23 but it seems to be installing 5.5.4.

I tried setting up the property 'ensure' to '5.6' but it gave me this error:

```
 Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install mysql-server=5.6' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: E: Version '5.6' for 'mysql-server' was not found
==> default: 
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Install/Package[mysql-server]/ensure: change from purged to 5.6 failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install mysql-server=5.6' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: E: Version '5.6' for 'mysql-server' was not found
==> default:
```

What can I do to install 5.6.23 ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `ensure`, use `package_name`. This worked for me:

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  package_name => 'mysql-server-5.6'
}
```

If incorrect version of `mysql-client` is being installed, add this as well:

```
class { '::mysql::client':
  package_name => 'mysql-client-5.6'
}
```

Comment: this does not work, since it tries to install mysql-client, which is version 5.5

Comment: Answer updated. You'll need to install the mysql-client package explicitly to get the correct version.